# Kendo Grid Date is null for 13/06/2015 all dates after 12

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<IBATechnologies.IBA.Web.Models.AssetTransactionDetailViewMod    el>()
    .Name("transactionGrid")
    .Pageable()
    //.Editable(editable=>editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Columns(colums =>
    {
        colums.Bound(p => p.assetCode).Width(100);
        colums.Bound(p => p.assetDesc).Width(100);
        colums.Bound(p => p.remark).Width(100);
        colums.Bound(p => p.currencyCode).Width(100);
        colums.Bound(p => p.rate).Width(100);
        colums.Bound(p => p.currencyRate).Width(100);
        colums.Bound(p => p.lcyAmount).Width(100);
        colums.Bound(p => p.documentDate).Width(100);
        colums.Command(command => { command.Destroy(); }).Width(100);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.assetCode))
        .Create(update => update.Action("TransactionDoc_Create", "AssetTransaction"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("TransactionDoc_Read", "AssetTransaction", new { docno = 0 }))
        .Update(update => update.Action("BrandEditingPopup_Update", "AssetTransaction"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("BrandEditingPopup_Destroy", "AssetTransaction"))
    )
)
```

My grid is shown above. When I try to edit, all the dates after 12 are returned as null. Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by dates after 12?

Comment: date 13/6/2015,14/6/2015.. etc

Comment: It looks like you need to change the culture for Kendo and/or the server.

Comment: What culture are you using?

Comment: @mmillican,@ataravati, thank you so much, issue is solved by adding culture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a culture issue.  Try changing your Kendo UI culture (by including one of the other culture JS files.  You may also need to change the culture on the server

Answer (score 0):

```
<script   src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2015.1.429/cultures/kendo.culture.en-GB.min.js")"></script>
<script>
   kendo.culture("en-GB");
</script>
```